# Die unregelmäßigen Verben / unregelmäßige Verben

Tags: article

Was ist korrekt? Ich habe versucht, das mithilfe der Bücher herauszufinden, aber die haben mir nicht geholfen: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unregelm%C3%A4%C3%9Fige+Verben+kennen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3.

1. Ich kenne englische unregelmäßige Verben.
2. Ich kenne die englischen unregelmäßigen Verben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Wort 'Verb' ist ein zählbares Nomen. Der artikellose Plural zählbarer Nomen bedeutet vereinfacht gesagt eine unbestimmte Anzahl verschiedener durch das Nomen bezeichneter Elemente:

> 2 Ich lese manchmal französische Zeitungen.

Der definite Artikel vor einem zählbaren Plural-Nomen bedeutet, wenn er nicht zeigend (quasi-demonstrativ) verwendet wird, entweder 'alle' bzw. 'überhaupt' (generalisierend):

> 4 Die deutschen unregelmäßigen Verben sind auch nicht schwerer zu lernen als ihre englischen Pendants

oder, wohl häufiger, eine Referenz auf irgendeine Art von Vorerwähntheit. Diese Vorerwähntheit muss nicht in demselben Dialog oder Text vorliegen, sie kann sich auch auf das Allgemeinwissen beziehen (*diese schrecklichen unregelmäßigen Verben, mit denen wir alle bereits im Schulalter geplagt wurden*):

> 5 Ich hatte beim Englischlernen einige Probleme, aber die [uns allen aus leidvoller Erfahrung bekannten] unregelmäßigen Verben gehörten für mich seltsamerweise nicht dazu.

Jedoch kann auch Artikellosigkeit (bzw. der 'Nullartikel') generalisierend eingesetzt werden:

> 6 Deutsche unregelmäßige Verben sind auch nicht schwerer zu lernen als ihre englischen Pendants.

Letzterer Satz wirkt auf mich entschiedener = weniger Widerspruch duldend, noch einen Tick 'genereller', allgemeingültiger als derselbe Satz mit 'die deutschen unregelmäßigen Verben' = Beispiel 4. Mit diesem 'die' passt er gut in einen Kontext, in dem diese Verben bereits Thema waren (Vorerwähntheit).

Wenn man versucht, so etwas wie 'semantische Minimalpaare' zu konstruieren, treten einzelne Aspekte deutlicher hervor:

> 7 Ich habe heute Nachmittag englische unregelmäßige Verben gelernt

bedeutet für mich: nicht alle, nur eine Auswahl davon.

> 8 Ich habe in den letzten zwei Wochen die englischen unregelmäßigen Verben gelernt

heißt für mich: tendenziell alle, jedenfalls alle, die in unserem Lehrbuch / in unserer Grammatik stehen.

> 9 Was brabbelst du da die ganze Zeit: go went gone - come came come, was soll das? - *Das sind englische unregelmäßige Verben.*

... jedenfalls ein paar davon.

> 10 Was ist das für eine Liste da auf den Tisch? - *Das sind die englischen unregelmäßigen Verben.*

= alle für mich aktuell relevanten.

Damit ist noch nicht alles gesagt. Die Bedeutung der Artikel bzw. der Artikellosigkeit changiert mit dem Kontext:

> 11 Was siehst du auf dem Foto? - *Ich sehe Kartoffeln.*

... und keine Karotten, also Art-bestimmend.

> 12 Isst du lieber Reis oder Nudeln oder Kartoffeln? - Ich mag am liebsten Kartoffeln

= generalisierend, bezogen auf meine Person.

> 13 Hast du Kartoffeln gekauft?

= irgendwelche, egal wie viele, wir hatten vorher auch nicht davon gesprochen, dass du Kartoffeln kaufen solltest..

> 14 Hast du an die Kartoffeln gedacht?

... die zu kaufen ich dich gebeten hatte = Vorerwähntheit.

Für mich bedeutet also der angefragte Satz 1 so etwas wie:

> So, du kennst also welche? Kannst du mir dann mal ein paar englische unregelmäßige Verben sagen?

Der Satz 2 bedeutet für mich:

> Ich habe die (alle oder zum großen Teil) gelernt, ich habe über sie jetzt einen gewissen Überblick, ich kenne sie jetzt zumindest in Grundzügen.